# Generic errors collection in a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that has input fields that dont' map to a model object.

How can I add errors during a post that will show up int he view page?

I have done the below before on other pages:

if @users.errors.any? and then I loop through the errors.fullmessages.each  on my other forms, but this time I can't really map to a particular model.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the flash hash, in which you could do the following:

Controller:

```
if @user.errors.any?
  flash[:user_errors] = @user.errors
end
```

View:

```
<% if flash[:user_error] %>
    # loop through errors
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's typical to use flash messages for that :

You can do a flash[:error] = 'Invalid Action' and then in your view :

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
    <%=h flash[:error] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yeah I need a collection, I guess any array will do then.